# jquery count elements with a particular class that have value greater than zero

Tags: jquery

Hi say I have some inputs:

```
<input type="Text" class="myclass" value="0" />
<input type="Text" class="myclass" value="7" />
<input type="Text" class="myclass" />
<input type="Text" class="myclass" value="2" />
```

And I want to count the number of inputs with class myclass that have a value greater than zero how would I go about that. In the scenario above the output I would want would be 2.

So far I have `$(".myclass").filter().length`

However I'm not sure what should go in filter or it I should even be using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(".myclass").filter(function(){
    return +this.value > 0;
}).length;
```

`+` casts the value to a number and then it just returns true if the value is greater than one and false if otherwise.  A function is passed to [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), this loops through each match. If the function returns `false` then the element is removed from the set so you're just left with elements whose value is greater than zero.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/88zH3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var count=$(".myclass").filter(function(){
     return $(this).val() >0;
}).length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".myclass").filter(function(el, i){
    return parseInt( $(el).val(), 10 ) > 0;
}).length;
```

Comment: Maybe add some context why this answers the question?